# FIrebase Query from React Returning Wrong Snapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a firebase firestore collection named `users` where the `username` is unique. The following code fetches the `username` who is logged in now as `currentUsername`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
      setLoading(false)
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  // currentUsername
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid)
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        setCurrentUsername(snapshot.data().username)
      })

    } else {
      setCurrentUsername()
    }
  }, [currentUser])
```

Then I have another collection named `messageboxes` where a filed is `requestBy`. I want to query all messageboxes where `requestBy===currentUsername`. So, my code is as follows.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUsername) {
      let db = firebase.firestore()
      setSentMessageBoxes([])

      db.collection("messageBoxes").where("requestBy", "==", currentUsername)
        .orderBy('lastTime', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          let result = []
          snapshot.forEach(sentBox => {
            console.log('requestBy', sentBox.requestBy) // logs -> test2 : another user
            console.log('current', currentUsername) // logs -> test : current user
            console.log('query', sentBox.requestBy===currentUsername) // logs -> false!!!
            result.push({id: sentBox.id, ...sentBox.data()})
          })

          setSentMessageBoxes(result)
    }
  }, [currentUsername])
```

I have no idea what is wrong with my query and it is returning some docs which do not fulfill the `.where("requestBy", "==", currentUsername)` condition. I am printing the value of `currentUsername` and it is totally ok. I am stuck on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to create an index for where and orderby query in firebase dashboard/firestore database/indexes.

Comment: I have created indexes. This is my index for `messageBoxes`: `messageBoxes-requestBy: Ascending, lastTime:Descending`. Should I edit this?

Comment: Do you need actually the onsnapshot instead of get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out the problem but somehow solved it. I have used two different contexts, one is `AuthContext` and the other is `MessageContext`.

AuthContext is responsible for authentication and authorization and MessageContext is fetching the message.

In `app.js`, I have coded like below:

```
    <AuthContext.Provider value={values}>
      <MessageContext.Provider value={values}>
      <MessageContext.Provider>
    <AuthContext.Provider>
```

Using them in separate contexts solved the problem.